# Confirm my understanding of adjoints

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators

adjoints seem REALLY important and useful so I don't want to move onto the next topic without really understanding them; I have too many a times moved on and been lost because I don't have the foundation I should.

Anyways, here goes my explanation of what I think the adjoint is. It's probably really wrong but that's what you guys are here for :):

We have a vector $v \in V$ where $V$ is an inner product space. By the Riesz Representation theorem, we can ALWAYS find a linear functional $T: V \to R$ (a transformation that takes a vector and spits out a scalar) such that $T_w(v) = \langle v,w \rangle$.

The Riesz Representation theorem also stipulates that $w$ is unique.

This is where my first few questions arise:

- Why is $w$ unique? Is it unique in that $\langle v,w\rangle$ only equals some value $x$ for a specific $w$ i.e. the linear functional is one-to-one and $x=\langle v,w\rangle$ for a specific $w$?
- What space is $w$ from? Is it in the same $V$ as $v$?

%__________________

Continuing with my explanation...

From the linear functional, $T_w(v) = \langle v,w\rangle$, we can define another linear functional $T^*_w(v)$ (the ADJOINT) that takes this UNIQUE $w$ and gives us back the corresponding $v$ with which we defined the first linear functional $T_w(v) =\langle v,w\rangle$

This is where my last few questions come up:

- What are the domain and codomains of the adjoint linear functional $T_w^*(v)$?
- Why does $\langle T(v),w\rangle = \langle v,T^*(w)\rangle$? Using the definitions I just gave wouldn't $\langle T(v),w\rangle = \langle \langle v,w\rangle, w\rangle$?

phew! that was long, haha. Any helpp would be appreciated! Thanks you guys!

Comment: Uniqueness here means that if there are two $w, w'$ such that $T=T_w$ and $T=T_{w'}$, then we can conclude that $w=w'$. This is true because if $\langle v, w \rangle = \langle v, w' \rangle$ for all $v \in V$, then $w=w'$ (Hint: check on an orthonormal basis).

Comment: Riesz Representation  works only on Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Thank you @NoahOlander, this makes sense!

Comment: @Crostul, I'll go ahead and look up what a Hilbert space is!

Comment: @DavidSouth No problem! And yeah, I think you should just add that $V$ is finite-dimensional in your question since the Riesz Representation doesn't hold in general inner product spaces.

Comment: @NoahOlander: The Riesz Th. holds in general Hilbert spaces for **bounded** linear functionals. In finite dimensional spaces all linear operator are bounded, but this is not true in infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: @EmilioNovati I'm aware, but lots of inner product spaces aren't Hilbert spaces. I think you've misinterpreted or glanced over my use of the word "general"!

Answer (score 1):

I think that he starting point is to well understand what a linear functional is and what is the dual space, i.e. the space of linear functionals.
We start with a vector space $V$ over a field $K$ nad we say that a function T$:V\rightarrow K$ is a linear functional iff 
$$T(a \vec u +b \vec v)=aT(\vec u)+bT(\vec v) \qquad \forall\; a,b \in K \quad \mbox{and}\quad \forall \;\vec u, \vec v \in V 
$$
Let $V^*$ the set of all such functionals, ve can prove that it is a vector space when equipped with the addition:
$$
(T+S)(\vec v)= T(\vec v)+S(\vec v)
$$
and the scalar multiplication
$$
(aT)(\vec v)= a \left(T(\vec v)\right)
$$
Such vector space $V^*$ is called the **algebraic dual** of $V$. Note that his elements are not vectors of $V$ but linear functionals.

Now, if $V$ is an Hilbert space of finite dimension $n$, the Riesz Representation Theorem say us that any element of this space $V^*$ can be represented as the inner product of  $\vec v \in V$ with a given vector $\vec t$, i.e.
$$
T(\vec v)= \langle \vec v, \vec t \rangle
$$
This result can be extended also to infinite dimensional spaces, but only for bounded linear functionals. In this case we have to distinguish the algebraic dual $V^*$ from the continuous (or topological) dual $V'$ that is the subspace $V'\subset V^*$ of continuous (bounded) functionals.
Here I avoid this problem limiting the discussion to finite dimensional spaces, where $V'=V^*$.

Here the key fact is that $T$ and $\vec t$ are two different things: $\vec t$ is a vector of $V$, $T$ is a linear functional i.e. an element of $V^*$. 
To highlight this difference ve can call $T$ a 1-form, or a dual vector, and $\vec t$ is a vector that in a well defined sense given by the RRT correspond to the 1-form $T$.

We can say that $\vec t$ defined by $\langle \vec v, \vec t\rangle \; \forall \vec v \in V$ is the *adjoint* of the 1-form $T$. But , in my opinion, it is better to reserve this term only for the adjoint of a linear operator and not use it for the functionals to avoid confusion..

Now we can go to your questions.

1) Why $\vec t$  (your $w$) is unique?

Given $T \in V^*$ such that $\langle \vec x,\vec t \rangle =T(\vec x)$ suppose that there is $\vec t'$ s.t.  $\langle \vec x,\vec t' \rangle =T(\vec x)$
Than we have :
$$
\langle \vec x, \vec t-\vec t' \rangle=\langle \vec x, \vec t\rangle -\langle\vec x,\vec t' \rangle= T(\vec x)-T(\vec x) = 0 \quad \forall \vec x \in V
$$
so , in particular, $\langle \vec t-\vec t',\vec t - \vec t'\rangle=0$ and this implies $\vec t= \vec t'$ .

(2) What space is $w$ from?

As you see $\vec t$ ( your $w$) is  a vector $\in V$, but, as just noticed, it is different form $T$.

About the other questions it seems that you have a bit of confusion deriving, I suppose, from the use of the term adjoint.  The '' adjoint'' ( if you want use this term) of a linear functional $T$ is simply the dual vector $\vec t$ of the 1-form $T$.

A different thing is the adjoint of a linear operator $A:V \rightarrow V$, that is defined as the operator $A^*$ such that:
$$
\langle \vec x,A^*(\vec y)\rangle=\langle A(\vec x),(\vec y)\rangle
$$
but note that you can not write a thing as $\langle T(\vec x),\vec y\rangle$ since $T(\vec x)$ is a scalar!.

A final note: The notation used here is the notation of mathematicians. Physicians use a bra-ket notation in which vectors are indicated as $\mid v\rangle$ ( kets) and linear functionals  as $\langle t\mid$ ( bra) so that the inner product become $\langle t\mid v \rangle$ that, in my opinion ( maybe because I was a physicist), is more expressive and clear.

Comment: Small English correction: a "physician" is a doctor, a "physicist" studies physics (I know it's strange).  Also, a LaTeX change: I think `\mid` looks better for Dirac notation than `|`.  Feel free to undo either change.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. My english is primitive :) and I was a physicist long time ago.